# console not show , supermicro server

Tags: console, supermicro, console-server

hope you have a good day.

This is my first time to configure a server. I'm facing small issue, after I login to  super micro server "remotely", the console not showing.

note that I already install java and update it. I tried in different devices and different browsers

[image]

Comment: The `latest` version might not always be the best. If the server is rather old you might need an older java version for it to work. Check the documentation of your server for compatibility.

Comment: thank you for your replay, do you know were can I find this Info ? i search about it and nothing came with me . my server is : 1028R-MCTR